# Trying to edit HTML/JavaScript Template - Image change onClick, but not automatic image rotation

Tags: javascript, html, image, onclick

:) I have a website that rotates 3 images (`images/1felpla.jpg`, `images/1nicehum.jpg`, `images/hummu.jpg`) every 6 seconds or so near the top of the webpage. You can navigate through the 3 pics with arrows and by clicking the arrows, which I want. However, the images rotate automatically which I don't want. Is there any JS code I can cut or modify here that will make that happen? I am kind of new to JS. Please let me know!

Here is the HTML:

```
<!-- Slide1 -->
<section class="section-slide">
    <div class="wrap-slick1">
        <div class="slick1">
            <div class="item-slick1 item1-slick1" style="background-image: url(images/1felpla.jpg);">
                <div class="wrap-content-slide1 sizefull flex-col-c-m p-l-15 p-r-15 p-t-150 p-b-170">
                    <span class="caption1-slide1 txt1 t-center animated visible-false m-b-15" data-appear="fadeInDown">
                        Dans
                    </span>

                    <h2 class="caption2-slide1 tit1 t-center animated visible-false m-b-37" data-appear="fadeInUp">
                        Diner
                    </h2>

                    <div class="wrap-btn-slide1 animated visible-false" data-appear="zoomIn">
                        <!-- Button1 -->
                        <a href="menu.html" class="btn1 flex-c-m size1 txt3 trans-0-4">
                            Menu
                        </a>
                        <br>
                        <div class="visible-on-mobile"> 
                            <a href="tel:555555555" class="btn1 flex-c-m size1 txt3 trans-0-4">Call</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="visible-on-desktop">
                            <a href="contact.html" class="btn1 flex-c-m size1 txt3 trans-0-4">Contact</a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item-slick1 item2-slick1" style="background-image: url(images/1nicehum.jpg);">
                <div class="wrap-content-slide1 sizefull flex-col-c-m p-l-15 p-r-15 p-t-150 p-b-170">
                    <span class="caption1-slide1 txt1 t-center animated visible-false m-b-15" data-appear="rollIn">
                        Dans 
                    </span>

                    <h2 class="caption2-slide1 tit1 t-center animated visible-false m-b-37" data-appear="lightSpeedIn">
                        Diner
                    </h2>

                    <div class="wrap-btn-slide1 animated visible-false" data-appear="slideInUp">
                        <!-- Button1 -->
                        <a href="menu.html" class="btn1 flex-c-m size1 txt3 trans-0-4">
                            Menu
                        </a>
                        <br>
                        <div class="visible-on-mobile"> 
                            <a href="tel:555555555" class="btn1 flex-c-m size1 txt3 trans-0-4">Call</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="visible-on-desktop">
                            <a href="contact.html" class="btn1 flex-c-m size1 txt3 trans-0-4">Contact</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item-slick1 item3-slick1" style="background-image: url(images/hummu.jpg);">
                <div class="wrap-content-slide1 sizefull flex-col-c-m p-l-15 p-r-15 p-t-150 p-b-170">
                    <span class="caption1-slide1 txt1 t-center animated visible-false m-b-15" data-appear="rotateInDownLeft">
                        Dans
                    </span>

                    <h2 class="caption2-slide1 tit1 t-center animated visible-false m-b-37" data-appear="rotateInUpRight">
                        Diner
                    </h2>

                    <div class="wrap-btn-slide1 animated visible-false" data-appear="rotateIn">
                        <!-- Button1 -->
                        <a href="menu.html" class="btn1 flex-c-m size1 txt3 trans-0-4">
                            Menu
                        </a>
                        <br>

                        <div class="visible-on-mobile"> 
                            <a href="tel:555555555" class="btn1 flex-c-m size1 txt3 trans-0-4">Call</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="visible-on-desktop">
                            <a href="contact.html" class="btn1 flex-c-m size1 txt3 trans-0-4">Contact</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



        <div class="wrap-slick1-dots"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
(function ($) {
// USE STRICT
"use strict";

    /*[ Slick1 ]
    ===========================================================*/
    var itemSlick1 = $('.slick1').find('.item-slick1');
    var action1 = [];
    var action2 = [];
    var action3 = [];
    var cap1Slide1 = [];
    var cap2Slide1 = [];
    var btnSlide1 = [];

    for(var i=0; i<itemSlick1.length; i++) {
      cap1Slide1[i] = $(itemSlick1[i]).find('.caption1-slide1');
      cap2Slide1[i] = $(itemSlick1[i]).find('.caption2-slide1');
      btnSlide1[i] = $(itemSlick1[i]).find('.wrap-btn-slide1');
    }


    $('.slick1').on('init', function(){

        action1[0] = setTimeout(function(){
            $(cap1Slide1[0]).addClass($(cap1Slide1[0]).data('appear') + ' visible-true');
        },200);

        action2[0] = setTimeout(function(){
            $(cap2Slide1[0]).addClass($(cap2Slide1[0]).data('appear') + ' visible-true');
        },1000);

        action3[0] = setTimeout(function(){
            $(btnSlide1[0]).addClass($(btnSlide1)[0].data('appear') + ' visible-true');
        },1800);              
    });


    $('.slick1').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        fade: true,
        dots: true,
        appendDots: $('.wrap-slick1-dots'),
        dotsClass:'slick1-dots',
        infinite: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 6000,
        arrows: true,
        appendArrows: $('.wrap-slick1'),
        prevArrow:'<button class="arrow-slick1 prev-slick1"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>',
        nextArrow:'<button class="arrow-slick1 next-slick1"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>',  
    });

    $('.slick1').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){ 
        for(var i=0; i<itemSlick1.length; i++) {

          clearTimeout(action1[i]);
          clearTimeout(action2[i]);
          clearTimeout(action3[i]);


          $(cap1Slide1[i]).removeClass($(cap1Slide1[i]).data('appear') + ' visible-true');
          $(cap2Slide1[i]).removeClass($(cap2Slide1[i]).data('appear') + ' visible-true');
          $(btnSlide1[i]).removeClass($(btnSlide1[i]).data('appear') + ' visible-true');

        }

        action1[currentSlide] = setTimeout(function(){
            $(cap1Slide1[currentSlide]).addClass($(cap1Slide1[currentSlide]).data('appear') + ' visible-true');
        },200);

        action2[currentSlide] = setTimeout(function(){
            $(cap2Slide1[currentSlide]).addClass($(cap2Slide1[currentSlide]).data('appear') + ' visible-true');
        },1000);

        action3[currentSlide] = setTimeout(function(){
            $(btnSlide1[currentSlide]).addClass($(btnSlide1)[currentSlide].data('appear') + ' visible-true');
        },1800);            
    });


    /*[ Slick2 ]
    ===========================================================*/
    var itemSlick2 = $('.item-slick2');
    var action1s2 = [];
    var cap1Slide2 = [];

    for(var i=0; i<itemSlick2.length; i++) {
      cap1Slide2[i] = $(itemSlick2[i]).find('.wrap-content-slide2 .blo2');
    }


    $('.slick2').on('init', function(){

        action1s2[0] = setTimeout(function(){
            $(cap1Slide2[0]).addClass($(cap1Slide2[0]).data('appear') + ' visible-true');
        },200);              
    });


    $('.slick2').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        fade: true,
        dots: true,
        appendDots: $('.wrap-slick2-dots'),
        dotsClass:'slick2-dots',
        infinite: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 6000,
        arrows: true,
        appendArrows: $('.wrap-slick2'),
        prevArrow:'<button class="arrow-slick2 prev-slick2"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>',
        nextArrow:'<button class="arrow-slick2 next-slick2"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>',  
    });

    $('.slick2').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){ 
        for(var i=0; i<itemSlick2.length; i++) {

          clearTimeout(action1s2[i]);

          $(cap1Slide2[i]).removeClass($(cap1Slide2[i]).data('appear') + ' visible-true');
        }

        action1s2[currentSlide] = setTimeout(function(){
            $(cap1Slide2[currentSlide]).addClass($(cap1Slide2[currentSlide]).data('appear') + ' visible-true');
        },200);            
    });


    /*[ Slick3 ]
    ===========================================================*/
    var itemSlick3 = $('.slick3').find('.item-slick3');
    var action1s3 = [];
    var action2s3 = [];
    var action3s3 = [];
    var cap1Slide3 = [];
    var cap2Slide3 = [];
    var btnSlide3 = [];

    for(var i=0; i<itemSlick3.length; i++) {
      cap1Slide3[i] = $(itemSlick3[i]).find('.pic-review');
      cap2Slide3[i] = $(itemSlick3[i]).find('.content-review');
      btnSlide3[i] = $(itemSlick3[i]).find('.more-review');
    }


    $('.slick3').on('init', function(){

        action1s3[0] = setTimeout(function(){
            $(cap1Slide3[0]).addClass($(cap1Slide3[0]).data('appear') + ' visible-true');
        },200);

        action2s3[0] = setTimeout(function(){
            $(cap2Slide3[0]).addClass($(cap2Slide3[0]).data('appear') + ' visible-true');
        },1000);

        action3s3[0] = setTimeout(function(){
            $(btnSlide3[0]).addClass($(btnSlide3)[0].data('appear') + ' visible-true');
        },1000);              
    });


    $('.slick3').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        fade: false,
        dots: true,
        appendDots: $('.wrap-slick3-dots'),
        dotsClass:'slick3-dots',
        infinite: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 6000,
        arrows: true,
        appendArrows: $('.wrap-slick3'),
        prevArrow:'<button class="arrow-slick3 prev-slick3"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>',
        nextArrow:'<button class="arrow-slick3 next-slick3"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>',  
    });

    $('.slick3').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){ 
        for(var i=0; i<itemSlick3.length; i++) {

          clearTimeout(action1s3[i]);
          clearTimeout(action2s3[i]);
          clearTimeout(action3s3[i]);


          $(cap1Slide3[i]).removeClass($(cap1Slide3[i]).data('appear') + ' visible-true');
          $(cap2Slide3[i]).removeClass($(cap2Slide3[i]).data('appear') + ' visible-true');
          $(btnSlide3[i]).removeClass($(btnSlide3[i]).data('appear') + ' visible-true');

        }

        action1s3[currentSlide] = setTimeout(function(){
            $(cap1Slide3[currentSlide]).addClass($(cap1Slide3[currentSlide]).data('appear') + ' visible-true');
        },200);

        action2s3[currentSlide] = setTimeout(function(){
            $(cap2Slide3[currentSlide]).addClass($(cap2Slide3[currentSlide]).data('appear') + ' visible-true');
        },1000);

        action3s3[currentSlide] = setTimeout(function(){
            $(btnSlide3[currentSlide]).addClass($(btnSlide3)[currentSlide].data('appear') + ' visible-true');
        },1000);            
    });




})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `autoplay` field to `false`

Comment: Im afraid ive tried that a few times now. I even changed the autoplay speed to 10 million but it didn't affect it. I changed browsing history then tried again. Not sure whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to do it:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```